# Tags: Bayes-network vs. Bayesian-network

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms, tag-wiki

I have noticed a user actively changing `bayes-network` tag into `bayesian-network`. Both tags have approximately the same number of questions (about 90 each), but neither has a description.

- Are they duplicates?
- Should one be removed?
- Could anyone create a wiki and an excerpt for the remaining one (or both)?

Comment: The user is doing this massively (right about now)! Someone should stop him before we are sure how to deal with the two tags.

Comment: I have made the two tags into synonyms.  (This is a reversible action, in case answers here suggest some other course is advisable.)  In the meantime the system has automatically blocked additional edit suggestions by that user.  The motivation for these changes appears reasonable; the problem is that a wholesale manual change of hundreds of threads is not the way to go about making them!

Comment: @whuber I found the user in question and looked at his edit comments. I agree with him that "Bayesian network" is the preferred term in the literature, so I think your synonym [bayes-network]$\to$[bayesian-network] is correct and can safely be merged (perhaps after a day or two, just in case somebody protests here).

Comment: I have put in a tag wiki for `Bayesian networks` and fully agree that `Bayes network` should be a synonym.

Comment: Sorry for being that user haha - I still don't understand the tagging process. I will avoid making any more similar edits in the near future. I'm just really interested in Bayesian networks and was frustrated that the separation of questions related to them was being split into two tags arbitrarily, making the interest on Cross Validated seem smaller than it was. Any suggestions for how to better approach such a problem in the future would be appreciated.

Comment: @William: no problem, and thank you for helping to organize the site. The problem with edits (like retags) is that edited posts are automatically pushed to the top of the active questions list - so each retag pushes off one *actual* new question, which receives a lot less attention once it's off the first page...

Comment: @William: ... the preferred way to deal with a situation like this is to propose a *tag synonym*, as was done here: the tag "bayes-network" will now automatically point to "bayesian-network". You can either propose such a synonym yourself once you hit 2,500 rep, or simply open a question here on Meta, and we will discuss it (or [just post here](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/q/1200/1352)). If you want to help organize the site, you are most welcome, and I'd recommend you browse a bit through Meta to get a feeling for how the community likes to do things. Welcome aboard!

Comment: @William, StephenKolassa is right. Your idea was good and helpful, but re-tagging is a somewhat special process. But your actions ultimately led to a better outcome!

Comment: @whuber: this appears to be resolved to everyone's satisfaction. Do you want to add the [tag:status-completed] tag?

Comment: @RichardHardy, consider posting an answer stating that the issue is resolved and accepting it, to mark this thread as resolved (otherwise your question remains both officially and visually "unanswered").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has been solved. Closing the thread.